# Dell Precision 7530 HDMI output not working

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, 20.04, hdmi

I am trying to get my HDMI output on my Dell Precision 7530 working. The USB-C to HDMI adapter works perfectly fine, but the HDMI output on the back does not. `xrandr` reports that `HDMI-1 disconnected`

What I have tried:

- lightdm
- Disconnecting the HDMI montitor and reconnecting it during after login.
- forcing the screen to display using `xrandr`
- running `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`
- Purging the nvidia drivers:

```
sudo apt-get purge 'nvidia*'
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update
```

- Using `prime-select` to switch between Intel and nVidia

During the install at one point I had a wierd thing happen where I had my HDMI monitor outputting the login screen and my laptop and USB-C monitor outputting the Dell boot screen logo. This went away after reboot, and that was the last time my HDMI monitor worked with ubuntu.

What can I do to get it working or am I just done for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by buying another USB C to DVI adapter and using that instead of the HDMI output on the back of the computer.

Answer (score -1):

I had this same problem and fixed it by installing the Radeon WX 4150 software. This instantly fixed my problem.

Hope this helps you as well!

Comment: What do you mean by "Radeon WX 4150 software"?